# Как подключить PostgreSQL к Java проекту?

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle

Ситуация следующая. Есть java-проект собранный в Gradle с подключением Rabbitmq. В качестве рабочей IDE использую Idea,работаю в Ubuntu. В pgAdmin создал простенькую базу с 2 таблицами. Хочу ее присобачить к проекту. Просмотрел туториалы,но они меня только запутали...

Comment: Не получается подключится?

Comment: Что вас там могло запутать, само подключение чистого JDBC - 4-6 строк?

Comment: Подключить к проекту в смысле чтобы во вкладке `database` можно было смотреть содержимое базы, или в смысле как сделать подключение к базе из программного кода?

Comment: cкачал JDBC42 Postgresql Driver, Version 9.4-1208, добавил его к проекту.теперь он у меня лежит в директории idea/libraries/postgresql_9_4_1208.xml. Далее последовал этому примеру.создал класс в который внес код отсюда http://j4web.ru/postgresql/podklyuchenie-k-subd-postgresql-s-pomoshhyu-jdbc-drajvera.html   класс PostgreSQLConnect. команды Logger, Level,PostgreSQLConnect  выделяет красным и пишет "Cannot resolve symbol". Может в gradle.build еще нужно прописать какие-то dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам понадобится библиотека подключения к БД(к примеру postgresql-9.4-1204.jdbc4.jar)
Ну и вот пример бина, который собственно и вернет вам DataSource

```
<bean id="postgres-ds" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
      <property name="databaseName" value="mydb"/>
      <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>
      <property name="user" value="admin"/>
      <property name="password" value="admin"/>
      <property name="dataSourceName" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="initialConnections" value="1"/>
      <property name="maxConnections" value="10"/>
</bean>
```

Это на случай, если я правильно вас понял, и именно не получается подключится к БД из проекта

Comment: jar-файл postgre я вроде добавил.
 он у меня лежит в директории idea/libraries/postgresql_9_4_1208.xml. Далее последовал этому примеру.создал класс в который внес код отсюда j4web.ru/postgresql/… класс PostgreSQLConnect. команды Logger, Level,PostgreSQLConnect выделяет красным и пишет "Cannot resolve symbol". Может в gradle.build еще нужно прописать какие-то dependencies?

Comment: Покажите весь листинг класса с подключением. Может вы случайно и скопировали имя пакета(package ru.j4web.examples.java.jdbc.jdbcpostgresqlconnect;) а у вас пакет с классом другой?

Comment: сюда листинг не влезет. по этой ссылке его можно увидеть http://j4web.ru/postgresql/podklyuchenie-k-subd-postgresql-s-pomoshhyu-jdbc-drajvera.html
проблему с командами Logger и Level решил. ему не нравится только PostgreSQLConnect

Comment: Может у вас имя файла класса и само описание разное? К примеру имя файла класса называется Test, а внутри написано public class PostgreSQLConnect ......

Comment: да точно,вы правы. торможу с утра.еще не проснулся. спасибо)

Comment: Не за что) Всегда рады помочь